# Validation for attribute in blazor

Tags: c#, validation, input, blazor

I'm learning C# with blazor, I wanted to know how I can validate an input of type file, so that it doesn't allow files larger than 3MB

Comment: InputFile will return a stream for you files. The length of the files is the length of the stream...

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(yourFile);
```

get the files byte size:

```
var fileBytes = file.Length;
```

turn bytes to MBs:

```
var fileMBs = fileBytes / (1024*1024);
```

Answer (score 0):

This example explains how to **upload files**(in svg format) in Blazor with the **InputFile** component. Pay attention to the variable **maxFileSize** that set the **maximum number of bytes** that can be supplied by the Stream.

FileUpload.razor.cs

```
private bool fileUploading;
private string filePath = "C:\\fileFolder\\file.svg";
private const int maxFileSize= 3 * 1024 * 1024; //3MB max size

private async Task UploadSvgFileAsync(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
  fileUploading = true;
  try
  {
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(e.File.Name);
    if (!fileExtension.Equals(".svg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      throw new Exception("SVG file is required.");

    var stream = e.File.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize);
    await using FileStream fs = new(filePath, FileMode.Create);
    await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //some error handling
  }
  fileUploading = false;
}
```

And in your FileUpload.razor component:

```
@if (fileUploading )
{
  <span>- File Uploading...</span>
}
<InputFile OnChange="@UploadSvgFileAsync" />
```

I recommend reading the following articles to learn how to properly work with files in Blazor apps:

[File Uploads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server)

[File Downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: thank you very much, i will read the article and try to make it work for my code